# R - evaluate the expression as a string

Tags: r, parsing

Is is possible to do something like,

```
x = function(n,v) paste("<rel name=\"",quote(n),"\" value=\"",quote(v),"\"/>",sep="")
```

so that `x(y,1)` produces,

```
"<rel name=\"y\" value=\"1\"/>"
```

of course this doesn't work and  instead produces,

```
"<rel name=\"n\" value=\"v\"/>"
```

Also I have a nagging feeling that this kind of operation has a technical name, anybody know what it is?

Essentially, it would be nice if I didn't have do x("y","1").

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `substitute`:

```
x = function(n,v) paste("<rel name=\"",substitute(n),"\" value=\"",
                        substitute(v),"\"/>",sep="")

x(y,1)
#[1] "<rel name=\"y\" value=\"1\"/>"
```

Or if you're going to have more complex expressions, `deparse(substitute(`:

```
x = function(n,v) paste("<rel name=\"",deparse(substitute(n)),"\" value=\"",
                        deparse(substitute(v)),"\"/>",sep="")

x(y + 2, 3)
#[1] "<rel name=\"y + 2\" value=\"3\"/>"
```

Comment: The semicolon will be used in almost of values for v. incidentally `quote` doesn't handle semicolons either.

Comment: @csta that's because that's not a valid R expression, as `;` signals end of expression, but you haven't closed your parentheses yet; in other words - that will never work, no matter what `x` is

Answer (score 1):

You could use `deparse(substitute()` or `match.call`. Note I have used `sprintf` as I find it easier to decipher than `paste` in these situations.

```
 xx <- function(n,v){
       x <- sapply(as.list(match.call())[-1],deparse)
        sprintf(fmt ='<rel name=\"%s\" value=\"%s\">',x['n'],x['v'])}
 xx(y,2)
 ## [1] "<rel name=\"y\" value=\"2\">"
 xx(y, fun(x,b,v))
 ## [1] "<rel name=\"y\" value=\"fun(x, b, v)\">"
```

Note that `x(y,fun(p;d))` will not parse as it is not a valid `R` expression (it won't get past the language intepreter to even start